# Circular Reference and Open datareader in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, parent-child

How can i solve this in MVC

i have following data model

```
public class Game
{
    public int GameID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; 
}

public class Player
{
    public int PlayerID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int GameID { get; set; }
    public virtual Game Game { get; set; }
}
```

In the Context class i am creating both datasets

```
    public DbSet<Game> Games { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
```

I now have a simple MVC controller that by means of a Get API should return a json dataset with a list of Games and per Game a list of Players...

I tried this implementation of the MVC controller

```
    public JsonResult Games()
    {
        var Games = db.Games;
        return Json(Games, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

With this, i get an error telling me there is already an open datareader.
I kind of understand that, but i don't have the knowledge to solve it.

in order to solve it i tried to put it into a List<>

```
    public JsonResult Games()
    {
        var Games = db.Games.ToList();
        return Json(Games, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

At that point i get a circular reference error. (i guess its coming from the virtual Game with each Player. but what if i need that?

what is a correct and simple way forward with this problem?

i suppose it must be a basic thing since its a basic parent/child configuration. but i am missing something.

Comment: Can you please add which exception you are facing?

Comment: a game has multiple players, which then in turn do belong to different games. EF has no idea how to insert/delete them (determine correct order). If game is supposed to be the inverse navigation property to players, configure it like that. Otherwise, remove a cascade delete path by using on delete no action (WillCascadeOnDelete(false)).

Comment: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Game_23DD4D297E2691F50FB8C725AD19E2C8515BFF41849592FD2558443A79BD0918'.

Comment: I am not looking to insert or delete it. i just want to retrieve it DevilCuichiro

Comment: this is the circular reference when serializing the object. Ignore the serialization of the inverse property in that case.

Comment: What is the correct way in EF to have that reverse navigation property?

Comment: The exception you are facing has nothing to do with EF. You should execute the query before giving it to the JSON serializer though.

Comment: Have you overriden Equals method? Can you show us your controller's constructor?

Comment: public class GameController : Controller
    {
        public MyContext db = new MyContext();

        public GameController()
        {
        }

Answer (score 1):

Circular reference error generally appears when we design our entities badly. It is something like we have

```
public class Bank
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
}

public class BankBranch
{
   public int Id;
   public string BranchName;
   public int BankId { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("BankId")]
   public virtual Bank Bank { get; set; }
}
```

When we create a company entity and try to add both `Bank` and `BankBranch` `IDs` in this company entity, VS gives an error while adding or updating migrations due to multiple jump points for `Bank` entity. If we have a design like below

```
public class Company
{
   public int Id;
   public int BankBranchId { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("BankBranchId")]
   public virtual BankBranch BankBranch { get; set; }
}
```

we can reach branch from company and bank from the branch like this:
`company.BankBranch.Bank`.

Even if we have well-structured design EF can give this error. I am simply using `ProxyCreationEnable` attribute for retrieving `Json` data from the controller.

```
public JsonResult GetAllBankList()
{
   db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
   var bankList = db.Banks.ToList();
   return Json(bankList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might turn off proxies to avoid circular references.

```
YourDbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
YourDbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabledLazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```